# How to use multiple field filters inside composite filter in firestore using rest API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

Proper way to use json payload with **composite** filter with **AND** operator in firestore

```
payload ={ "structuredQuery": {
     "where" : {"compositeFilter":{
                                    "op":"AND",
                                    "filters":[
                                       { "fieldFilter":{"field" : {
                                                                  "fieldPath" : "address",
                                                                  },
                                                        "op": "EQUAL",
                                                        "value" : {"stringValue" :"gg"}
                                                       }
                                       }, 
                                      {"fieldFilter": {"field" :{
                                                             "fieldPath" : "name",
                                                                },
                                                       "op": "EQUAL",
                                                       "value" : {"stringValue" :"Abc"}
                                                      }
                                       }],
                                  }
               },
             "from" : [{"collectionId": "Test"}]
   }
```

}

**Note :** I am using firestore rest API

Comment: I tried out your request in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.runQuery) and it worked for me. Are you receiving an error?

Comment: No it's working correctly. Thanks for your response